# Snnowflake - COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import

Tags: amazon-s3, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, stage, unload

I'm trying to unload data from my table from snowflake to s3, like this:

```
COPY INTO "@DATABASE.SCHEMA.MY_STAGE/my_view/year=2023/month=04/day=21/my_view_data.parquet"
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table
    WHERE to_date(event_time) = '2023-04-21'
)
HEADER = true
```

But I'm receiving this error:
`COPY statement only supports simple SELECT from stage statements for import`

I don't understand why, I've created my stage with format file = parquet.
I've tried before without the header = true and it worked. Has someone any thoughts?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The `header = true` option is only for when you're reading from a stage and copying to a table https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.

In this case, you're reading from a table and copying to a stage. This has different options: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.

If your source file(s) have a header, then you would use a file format to handle that. In this case since it's parquet, you wouldn't need that option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
In fact, the error was because I was using double quotes and not single :)